# Symfony complications getting from dev to prod

Tags: symfony, debugging

Basically I had my website created by a company, but they did not change it to prod - that is probably why another person can gain access to the website without any ftp info. I need to have this fixed.

I read on the net that there should be a few folders in my root file like dev and prod, but I see none. I have only one folder with a custom name that contains all the files. Could you guys let me know how to change it to prod that all the debug tools and stuff are blocked?

Comment: There is a couple of steps to take when deploying to prod. It sounds to me like there is something wrong in your setup though. Could you post a screenshot of your files and file structure?

From the docs: https://symfony.com/doc/current/deployment.html

Answer (score 0):

Run the following commands if you are on `*nix` type OS:

**Step 1**

Symfony 2

`sudo rm -rf ./app/cache/*`

`sudo rm -rf ./app/logs/*`

Symfony 3

`sudo rm -rf ./var/cache/*`

`sudo rm -rf ./var/logs/*`

**Step 2**

```
HTTPDUSER=`ps axo user,comm | grep -E '[a]pache|[h]ttpd|[_]www|[w]ww-data|[n]ginx|lampp|xampp' | grep -v root | head -1 | cut -d\  -f1 PHPSTORMUSER=ps axo user,comm | grep -E 'storm' | grep -v root | head -1 | cut -d\  -f1`
```

**Step 3**

Symfony 2

```
sudo setfacl -R -m u:"$HTTPDUSER":rwX -m u:`whoami`:rwX app/cache app/logs
```

Symfomy 3

```
sudo setfacl -R -m u:"$HTTPDUSER":rwX -m u:`whoami`:rwX var/cache app/logs
```

**Step 4**

Symfony 2

```
sudo setfacl -dR -m u:"$HTTPDUSER":rwX -m u:`whoami`:rwX app/cache app/logs
```

Symfony 3

```
sudo setfacl -dR -m u:"$HTTPDUSER":rwX -m u:`whoami`:rwX var/cache var/logs
```

**Step 5**

`export SYMFONY_ENV=prod`

**Step 6**

`composer install --no-dev --optimize-autoloader`

These steps will remove all `dev` dependencies and will install `prod` dependencies according to `composer.json` config.

Comment: As I said I am a newbie and i have no idea where is the co sole.

I just have the files on my hosting, can I modify them manually?

Ill send the screen of file structure in few hours when i am home.

Thanks for help so far